# Program or Thunderbird add-on to automatically enter calendar data

Tags: windows, calendar, automation, thunderbird

At work we use a CalDAV calendar which is accessed via Thunderbird with the Lightning add-on.

The problem is I log exactly the same thing with exactly the same title every day of the working week, all year round. Despite this, I often forget to fill out my calendar.

What I would like is a program or Thunderbird add-on that will automate this task for me, but is smart enough to not create an entry where there already is one for the day or part of the day in which I work.

Requirements:

- Automatically enters necessary calendar data (title, start time, end time)
- Will run at regular intervals, either once per day at specified time, or once per week at specified day & time
- Must not create entries if an all day entry exists, or if other entries exist between the start time and end time
- Must run on Windows 7